# Cascading Dropdown list in html not working when appended

Tags: javascript, html

I have a cascading dropdown lists (or dependant dropdown lists) using javascript which works fine. I would like to be able to append the html with this cascading dropdown list. The issue i'm now having is, when I append the html the dropdown list in the appended html doesn't work. Not sure how to rectify this, any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
    <html>
       <head>
    

    <!--CASCADING JS-->
    
       <script>
        var subjectObject = {
        "Mattress": {
          "75x30x3":["20", "22", "35"],
          "75x30x4":["20", "22", "35"],
          "75x30x6":["20", "22", "35"],
          "75x36x3":["20", "22", "35"],
    },
        "Orthopaedic": {
         "75x54x6":["N/A"],
         "75x54x8":["N/A"],
         "75x54x10":["N/A"],
    },
       "Block": {
         "108":["13", "16", "18", "20", "22", "35"],
         "88":["13", "16", "18", "20", "22", "35"], 

    }
     window.onload = function() {
       var subjectSel = document.getElementById("subject");
       var topicSel = document.getElementById("topic");
       var chapterSel = document.getElementById("chapter");
       for (var x in subjectObject) {
       subjectSel.options[subjectSel.options.length] = new Option(x, x);
    }
       subjectSel.onchange = function() {       
       //empty Chapters- and Topics- dropdowns
       chapterSel.length = 1; topicSel.length = 1;
      //display correct values
       for (var y in subjectObject[this.value]) {
      topicSel.options[topicSel.options.length] = new Option(y, y);
    }
    }
     topicSel.onchange = function() { //empty Chapters dropdown chapterSel.length = 1;
    //display correct values
    var z = subjectObject[subjectSel.value][this.value];
    for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
      chapterSel.options[chapterSel.options.length] = new Option(z[i], z[i]);
    }
    }
  
    }
     </script>
    
    <!---END OF CASCADING JS-->

    <!------ START OF APPENDED JS--------->
         <script> //START OF APPENDED HTML (via JS)
        function myFunction() {
         var html = 
        '<div class="container">' +
                '<div class="grid-item">' +
                    '<label for="itempurchased">' +
                        '<span style="color:darkred; font-size:14px; padding-top: -14px">Item: 
    </span>' +
                    '</label>' +
                '</div>' +                         
                                   
        '<div class="grid-item">' +
            '<select name="subject" id="subject">' +
                '<option value="" selected="selected" style="font-style: italic">Select Item</option>' +
            '</select>' +
        '</div>' +      

                '<div class="grid-item">' +
                    '<label for="size">' +
                        '<span style="color:darkred; font-size:14px">Size:</span>' +
                    '</label>' +
                '</div>' +

        '<div class="grid-item">' +
            '<select name="topic" id="topic">' +
                '<option value="" selected="selected" style="font-style: italic">Select Size</option>' +
            '</select>' +
            '</div>' +  


                '<div class="grid-item">' +
                    '<label for="density">' +
                        '<span style="color:darkred; font-size:14px">Density:</span>' +
                    '</label>' +
                '</div>' +

                
        '<div class="grid-item">' +
            '<select name="chapter" id="chapter">' +
                '<option value="" selected="selected" style="font-style: italic">Select Density</option>' +
            '</select>' +
        '</div>' +  

                '<div class="grid-item">' +
                    '<label for="qty">' +
                        '<span style="color:darkred; font-size:14px">Qty:</span>' +
                    '</label>' +
                '</div>' +

                '<div class="grid-item">' +
                    '<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty">' +
                '</div>' +

        '</div>' +
        '<hr>';
            
    $('div.additem').append(html).trigger('create');
    }
                 
    </script>
    <!------ END OF APPENDED HTML--------->
    
    </head>

    <body>
        <html>
        HTML
        <form> 
        <div class="sales"> 
        <div class="customer">
             <label for="customer"> Customer Name:</label> <input type="text" name="customername" id="customername">
        </div>
            <hr>
        
        <div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="grid-item">
                    <label for="itempurchased">
                        <span style="color:darkred; font-size:14px; padding-top: -14px">Item: 
        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>                         
                                   
        <div class="grid-item">
            <select name="subject" id="subject">
                <option value="" selected="selected" style="font-style: italic">Select Item</option>
            </select>
        </div>      

                <div class="grid-item">
                    <label for="size">
                        <span style="color:darkred; font-size:14px">Size:</span>
                    </label>
                </div>

        <div class="grid-item">
            <select name="topic" id="topic">
                <option value="" selected="selected" style="font-style: italic">Select Size</option>
            </select>
        </div>  


                <div class="grid-item">
                    <label for="density">
                        <span style="color:darkred; font-size:14px">Density:</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            <div class="grid-item">
            <select name="chapter" id="chapter">
                <option value="" selected="selected" style="font-style: italic">Select Density</option>
            </select>
        </div>  
    
        <div class="grid-item">
            <label for="qty">
                <span style="color:darkred; font-size: 14px">Qty:</span>
            </label>
        </div>  

              <div class="grid-item">
            <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty">
        </div>

    </div>
    <hr>
        <!--div for add item-->
        <div class="additem"></div>
        </div>
    <!--------------ACTION BUTTONS------------->
    <div class="payment">
        <input type="submit" value="GO TO PAYMENT" name="btnSubmit" data-theme="d" id="btnSubmit" data-ajax="false">
    </div>
        
    <div class="add_item">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" data-theme="d" data-corners="5px" type="button">ADD ITEM</button>
    </div>
        
    </div>
</form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few syntax errors in your JS code:

1. Missing closing curly brace, before `window.onload = function...`, to match the opening one of `var  subjectObject = {`
2. On line 7 of your second script, you have a new line after `Item:`. Your code could use some formatting love.

https://jsfiddle.net/02ejx9wq/

```js
        var subjectObject = {
          "Mattress": {
            "75x30x3": ["20", "22", "35"],
            "75x30x4": ["20", "22", "35"],
            "75x30x6": ["20", "22", "35"],
            "75x36x3": ["20", "22", "35"],
          },
          "Orthopaedic": {
            "75x54x6": ["N/A"],
            "75x54x8": ["N/A"],
            "75x54x10": ["N/A"],
          },
          "Block": {
            "108": ["13", "16", "18", "20", "22", "35"],
            "88": ["13", "16", "18", "20", "22", "35"],

          }
        }
        window.onload = function() {
          var subjectSel = document.getElementById("subject");
          var topicSel = document.getElementById("topic");
          var chapterSel = document.getElementById("chapter");
          for (var x in subjectObject) {
            subjectSel.options[subjectSel.options.length] = new Option(x, x);
          }
          subjectSel.onchange = function() {
            //empty Chapters- and Topics- dropdowns
            chapterSel.length = 1;
            topicSel.length = 1;
            //display correct values
            for (var y in subjectObject[this.value]) {
              topicSel.options[topicSel.options.length] = new Option(y, y);
            }
          }
          topicSel.onchange = function() { //empty Chapters dropdown chapterSel.length = 1;
            //display correct values
            var z = subjectObject[subjectSel.value][this.value];
            for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
              chapterSel.options[chapterSel.options.length] = new Option(z[i], z[i]);
            }
          }

        }

        function myFunction() {
          var html =
            '<div class="container">' +
            '<div class="grid-item">' +
            '<label for="itempurchased">' +
            '<span style="color:darkred; font-size:14px; padding-top: -14px">Item:  </span>' +
            '</label>' +
            '</div>' +

            '<div class="grid-item">' +
            '<select name="subject" id="subject">' +
            '<option value="" selected="selected" style="font-style: italic">Select Item</option>' +
            '</select>' +
            '</div>' +

            '<div class="grid-item">' +
            '<label for="size">' +
            '<span style="color:darkred; font-size:14px">Size:</span>' +
            '</label>' +
            '</div>' +

            '<div class="grid-item">' +
            '<select name="topic" id="topic">' +
            '<option value="" selected="selected" style="font-style: italic">Select Size</option>' +
            '</select>' +
            '</div>' +


            '<div class="grid-item">' +
            '<label for="density">' +
            '<span style="color:darkred; font-size:14px">Density:</span>' +
            '</label>' +
            '</div>' +


            '<div class="grid-item">' +
            '<select name="chapter" id="chapter">' +
            '<option value="" selected="selected" style="font-style: italic">Select Density</option>' +
            '</select>' +
            '</div>' +

            '<div class="grid-item">' +
            '<label for="qty">' +
            '<span style="color:darkred; font-size:14px">Qty:</span>' +
            '</label>' +
            '</div>' +

            '<div class="grid-item">' +
            '<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty">' +
            '</div>' +

            '</div>' +
            '<hr>';

          $('div.additem').append(html).trigger('create');
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML
<form>
  <div class="sales">
    <div class="customer">
      <label for="customer"> Customer Name:</label> <input type="text" name="customername" id="customername">
    </div>
    <hr>

    <div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="grid-item">
          <label for="itempurchased">
            <span style="color:darkred; font-size:14px; padding-top: -14px">Item:
            </span>
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item">
          <select name="subject" id="subject">
            <option value="" selected="selected" style="font-style: italic">Select Item</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item">
          <label for="size">
            <span style="color:darkred; font-size:14px">Size:</span>
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item">
          <select name="topic" id="topic">
            <option value="" selected="selected" style="font-style: italic">Select Size</option>
          </select>
        </div>


        <div class="grid-item">
          <label for="density">
            <span style="color:darkred; font-size:14px">Density:</span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
          <select name="chapter" id="chapter">
            <option value="" selected="selected" style="font-style: italic">Select Density</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item">
          <label for="qty">
            <span style="color:darkred; font-size: 14px">Qty:</span>
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item">
          <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty">
        </div>

      </div>
      <hr>
      <!--div for add item-->
      <div class="additem"></div>
    </div>
    <!--------------ACTION BUTTONS------------->
    <div class="payment">
      <input type="submit" value="GO TO PAYMENT" name="btnSubmit" data-theme="d" id="btnSubmit" data-ajax="false">
    </div>

    <div class="add_item">
      <button onclick="myFunction()" data-theme="d" data-corners="5px" type="button">ADD ITEM</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```